# Setting a large NSDictionary property on a non-main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsdictionary, grand-central-dispatch

I have a class called `Dictionary`, where the `init` method looks like this:

```
- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        [self makeEmojiDictionaries];
    }

    return self;
}
- (void)makeEmojiDictionaries{

    //next line triggers bad_exc_access error 
    self.englishEmojiAllDictionary = @{@"hi" : @""}; //this is a strong, atomic property of NSDictionary
};
```

My issue is that the actual emoji dictionary is quite large, and I want to do all the heavy lifting in a **non-main thread** using GCD. However, whenever I get to the line where I set `self.englishEmojiAllDictionary`, I always get a `bad_access` error.

I am using GCD in the most normal way possible:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        //Do long process activity
        Dictionary *dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];

    });
```

Are there particular nuances to GCD or non-main thread work that I am missing? Any help is much appreciated - thank you!

**Edit 1:**

In case you'd like to try it yourself. I have uploaded a [sample project](https://github.com/zallanx/SampleDictionaryProject) that replicates this exception. My theory is that the `NSDictionary` I am initialization is simply too large.

Comment: From which class Dictionary derives?

Comment: Hi @Shripada, `Dictionary` inherits from `NSObject`

Comment: Your example doesn't actually set `englishEmojiAllDictionary`. It's unclear where you're crashing. Are you writing to `englishEmojiAllDictionary` anywhere else, or are all other callers readonly? Is `englishEmojiAllDictionary` public or private (can external objects access it directly or only by calling methods on `Dictionary`)? If you're not reading on a queue other than "My Queue" then you're going to have collisions, but you would expect the crash to be on the reader, not the writer. Do you do anything to make sure there are not readers before `makeEmojiDictionaries` completes?

Comment: Is the `self` still valid when your parsing finishes? I would probably start by enabling zombies.

Comment: I am trying hard to reproduce your issue but your example works correctly wherever I put it.

Comment: The real code obviously isn't just assigning that dictionary; can you try splitting creation of the dictionary from assignment to the instance variable, and see which is at fault? Also you really don't need to create a queue for this, just dispatch to the normal background queue. I can't see a single thing wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @RobNapier , and for the debugging suggestions. I'm not writing to `englishEmojiAllDictionary` anywhere else.  The only calls to `englishEmojiAllDictionary` happens when I call the line `Dictionary *dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];` `englishEmojiAllDictionary` is public. While another object does use it down the road, there are explicit steps to take to get there.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan - I'll upload a sample project and then edit my answer so you can see where I am having issues. Thanks for replicating.

Comment: Interesting discovery @Tommy - I realized that once the NSDictionary got to be large enough (more than 2k rows at the moment), it would throw the exc_bad_access error. Is this because the background thread is doing too much heavy lifting?

Comment: I think this will be somehow connected to the actual data, e.g. invalid `NSString` somewhere, some encoding problem, for example. Nothing easier than to test the actual loading on a command line Obj-C app from the `main` function.

Comment: @Sulthan I have been diligent about invalid NSStrings, and later realized that it may be due to the size of the `NSDictionary`. I uploaded a sample project in an Edit to the original question in case you'd like to replicate the issue.

Comment: Okey, I guess it's really the size of the dictionary, it probably takes too much memory in some internal static storage, I am trying to move the data into a plist to see if there is a difference.

Comment: Okey, putting the data into a plist works, I will put that as an answer soon.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a ton of duplication in that data. Many of the keys are the same, so the dictionary is actually much smaller than it looks.

Comment: @RobNapier Hi Rob, that's indeed the case. I duplicated the dictionary to show that it crashes when the size of the dictionary gets to be too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have moved your data from code to a `plist` file in the form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>arancia meccanica</key><string>⏰</string>
<key>uno freddo</key><string></string>
<key>un drink</key><string></string>
...
<key>bacio</key><string></string>
<key>baci</key><string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(I took your data and used find-replace three times: `",` => `</string>`, then `":@"` => `</key><string>` and `@"` => `<key>`).

Then I have loaded the data using:

```m
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dictionary" 
                                                     ofType:@"plist"]
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

That has fixed the problem. Note that you should *never* hardcode your data into source code.

The exact reason for the bug was pretty hard to pinpoint. The `NSDictionary` literal uses method `+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:]`.
My assembler knowledge is very poor but I think that before calling this initializer, all the keys & values are put on the stack.

However, there is a difference between the stack size of the main thread and the stack size of the background thread (see [Creating Threads in Thread Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)).

That's why the issue can be seen when executing the code on the background thread. If you had more data, the issue would probably appear on the main thread too.

The difference between stack size on main thread and background thread can be also demonstrated by the following simple code:

```
- (void)makeEmojiDictionaries {
    // allocate a lot of data on the stack
    // (approximately the number of pointers we need for our dictionary keys & values)
    id pointersOnStack[32500 * 2];

    NSLog(@"%i", sizeof(pointersOnStack));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the `plist` form. This seems promising for large datasets, and I'll try to replicate it and see what the results are, and then approve the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you use a file (plist, txt, xml, ...) to store large data, then read it at runtime, or download it from a remote server.

For your issue, it is because of the limitation of stack size. **On iOS, the default stack size for the main thread is 1 MB, and 512 KB for the secondary threads.** You can check it out via `[NSThread currentThread].stackSize`.
Your hardcoded dictionary costs almost 1 MB of stack, that is why your app will be crash on a secondary thread, but be OK on the main thread.

If you want to do this work on a background thread, you must increase the stack size for that thread.
For example:

```
// NSThread way:
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(populateDictionaries) object:nil];
thread.stackSize = 1024*1024;
[thread start];
```

Or

```
// POSIX way:
#include <pthread.h>

static void *posixThreadFunc(void *arg) {
    Dictionary *emojiDictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];
    return NULL;
}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pthread_t posixThread;
    pthread_attr_t  stackSizeAttribute;
    size_t          stackSize = 0;
    pthread_attr_init (&stackSizeAttribute);
    pthread_attr_getstacksize(&stackSizeAttribute, &stackSize);
    if (stackSize < 1024*1024) {
        pthread_attr_setstacksize (&stackSizeAttribute, REQUIRED_STACK_SIZE);
    }
    pthread_create(&posixThread, &stackSizeAttribute, &posixThreadFunc, NULL);
}

@end
```

Or

```
// Create mutable dictionary to prevent stack from overflowing
- (void)makeEmojiDictionaries {
   NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   dict[@"arancia meccanica"] = @"⏰";
   dict[@"uno freddo"] = @"";
   dict[@"un drink"] = @"";
   .....
   self.englishEmojiAllDictionary = [dict copy];
}
```

FYI:

- [Thread Costs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW7)
- [Customizing Process Stack Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1419/_index.html)

Comment: First I thought that you are just copying my answer but you are actually adding interesting information. By the way, the dictionary does not take 1 MB on the stack, it takes `number_of_items * 2 * sizeof(id)` which for 32k rows is about 512 kB.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, thank you to point that. I mean, the stack size needed to execute that thread work is almost 1 MB, which includes the reserved size for local variables and some bookkeeping data.

Comment: Really helpful stuff, especially the suggestion for using a `NSMutableDictionary` is very interesting. Quick question, in terms of retrieving information, would a mutable Dictionary be just as efficient as a non-mutable one?

Comment: @daspianist `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` means "manual memory allocation" to store a dictionary in the **heap**. The  `@{ ... }` way means memory allocation will be done by system to store dictionary in the **stack**, so it maybe overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @ElfSundae.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern when you need to do something slow is to do the work privately on a background queue, and then dispatch back to the main queue to make the completed work available to the rest of the app. In this case, you don't need to create your own queue. You can use one of the global background queues.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Dictionary.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) Dictionary *dictionary;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self updateViews];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{
        Dictionary *dictionary = [[Dictionary alloc] init];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _dictionary = dictionary;
            [self updateViews];
        });
    });
}

- (void)updateViews {
    if (self.dictionary == nil) {
        // show an activity indicator or something
    } else {
        // show UI using self.dictionary
    }
}

@end
```

Loading the dictionary from a file is a good idea, and you can do that in the background queue and then dispatch back to the main thread with the loaded dictionary.

Comment: While this is useful, unfortunately it does not address the root of the issue - this will still crash.

Comment: How so? I downloaded daspianist's sample project. It didn't crash for me. These modifications also don't crash for me. Explain how to make this crash.

Comment: Xcode 7.3, Simulator 6s Plus, it crashes for me without changes.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the global background queue - I think this is more efficient than making my own queue. Unfortunately, it's still causing the exception to occur. I think using the plist format with the global background queue would be the best combination, and will report back soon.